# How run AWS Device Farm TestNG Test file on Local Appium

Tags: amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

I Have TestNG script that run on aws devicefarm, i want to test it on my local appium on my android devices,

Can i know how to run on my local device?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test an Appium test package locally, you would set the [desired capabilities](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/).

An example of what that might look like for Android is:

`` {
    "platformName": "Android",
    "platformVersion": "11.0",
    "deviceName": "Find device name using `adb devices`",
    "automationName": "uiautomator/uiautomator2",
    "app": "/path/to/my.apk"
} ``

Here is a link to the samples that appium provides on their github.

https://github.com/appium/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples

Generally speaking, you wouldn't follow this pattern for testing on Device Farm. That is; you should develop the tests locally and then test on Device Farm.

I hope this helps. Feel free to let me know if there are any additional questions.